# Perl string works from command prompt but not from system() in CGI script

Tags: python, perl, cgi, mod-perl

Within my CGI script:

```
system("/home/httpd/cgi-bin/hbplus/hbplus /home/httpd/html/pdb1wdk.ent");

print $?;
```

The system command is passes a file (e.g. `pdb1wdk.ent`) as to `hbplus`. This is an exe file written in C which processes the input file to generate an output file.

The command works perfectly from the command prompt and creates a file in the present working directory, but not when it is run from my CGI script using `system`.

I've also tried running `hbplus` from a Python script and a shell script and calling these from the Perl CGIbut this gives a segmentation fault.

Comment: *"but when this is supposed to run from the browser"* -- what? How exactly does it not work?

Comment: First of all, what is with the "\*\*\*system....);\*\*\*" stuff? Second, the part before the system command appears to not do anything other than to define the variable $file, which is not used subsequently. Is this the entire script?

Comment: @KeithThompson actually a browser has option for the user to upload the file... ive just give an instance /home/httpd/html/pdb1wdk.ent... the perl script has to run the c file and give users file as input to this c file... and it would generate a output... thanks for the reply

Comment: @Radix thanks for the reply . The cgi script has to run the hbplus, which is a c generated exe. the input to it is a file. When i run the command in the prompt it works.But same command in system of perl it doesnt.

Comment: @pramod: Was that supposed to be an answer to my question? You say it doesn't work when it's run from the browser; what symptoms are you seeing? Any error messages?

Comment: Please tell us what happens when the `system` command fails. What error messages do you get? What is the value of `$?` that is displayed?

Comment: @KeithThompson Thompson my sincere apologies. I just want to run a command that i generally use on the command prompt to create the output file its a biological simulation. im new to perl cgi. I just tried putting the same command in system and ran the same. I is not creating the output file in ~/cgi-bin/. i can give u the file u can try running it

Comment: @KeithThompson there is a apache server running in our lab. we just want to include this extra operation on user uploaded file

Comment: @pramod: Thank you. That is *important information* that you should have included from the start. It means the `hbplus` process died from a segmentation error and dumped core. "It won't work" isn't any help at all.

Comment: @Borodin yup... but the same thing works very fine on the terminal what could be the reason ?

Comment: pramod Did you find the solution? I wanted to know because I am also getting the same error. @Borodin your suggestion didn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

A value of 139 - `0x8B` - for `$?` means it is failing because of a segmentation violation - SIGSEGV - and there is a core dump.

My best guess is that when your C program runs from the CGI account it doesn't have the necessary permissions to open the input file, and in addition it doesn't handle an open failure properly so it goes on to work with an invalid filehandle.

Change the permissions on `pdb1wdk.ent` with something like

```
chmod 744 pdb1wdk.ent
```

and see if the symptoms change.

If this works, don't forget to go back and change `hbplus` so that it handles a file open exception properly

Comment: thank you for the reply... i changed the permission hbplus is a compiled application i am not allowed to make any changes...

Comment: details of hbplus : http://www.bio.net/bionet/mm/bio-soft/1994-August/008380.html

Comment: Did this solution work for you? If so then you should at least report the problem with `hbplus` to your manager. Tell them Borodin says it needs fixing :)